# Convergence of means + convergence in probability implies convergence in mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value

Does convergence of mean coupled with convergence in probability imply convergence in mean?

Too me it seems like it does, but I am struggling for a formal proof.

Can someone help me prove this formally (if it is true in the first place)?

Comment: By convergence of mean, are you describing $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to \mathbb{E}(X)$ or $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|)\to \mathbb{E}(|X|)$?

Comment: I meant the first one.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** It does for non-negative random variables (cf. "Scheffé's Lemma"). If $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in probability and $\lim_n\Bbb E(X_n) = \Bbb E (X)<\infty$, consider the identity $|X-X_n| = 2(X-X_n)^++X_n-X$.

**2.** When the $X_n$ take both signs, things can go wrong. Consider, for example, $X_n=0$ with probability $1-1/n$ and $=\pm n$ with probability $1/2n$ for each sign.